# Understanding Spring MVC application contexts

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to understand basic Spring MVC stuff.

Consider the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Also consider below diagram that is given in the [official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-servlet):

[image]

Doubts:

1. What is precise types of instances created by `DispatcherServlet` and `ContextLoaderListener`? The confusion arise, since some articles online say `ContextLoaderListener` creates `ApplicationContext` instance and `DispatcherServlet` creates `WebApplicationContext` instance. But, after looking at their source, I feel both create instance of type `WebApplicationContext`, and since its subtype of `ApplicationContext`, some articles say `ContextLoaderListener` creates `ApplicationContext` instance. Is it also the case that only `ApplicationContext`-provided functionalities of instance created by `ContextLoaderListener` are used, and hence the article say `ContextLoaderListener` creates `ApplicationContext`, but not `WebApplicationContext`
   `
2. Is it like the `WebApplicaionContext` created by `ContextLoaderListener` is what [usually online articles refer to as](https://i.postimg.cc/s2CKv8b0/webappcontext.png) "root" `WebApplicationContext`, just to differentiate it from `WebApplicationContext`s created by `DispatcherServlet`?
3. Reading [this article](https://simone-folino.blogspot.com/2012/05/dispatcherservlet-vs.html), I understood that `DispatcherServlet` loads from `[servlet-name]-servlet.xml` file which should load "web tier components". On the other hand `ContextLoaderListener` loads "middle tier components". Given that there can be only one `ContextLoaderListener` in web.xml (right?), there should be only single single set of "middle tier components", whereas, since there can be multiple `DispatcherServlet`s, there can be multiple sets of "web tier components". Is this right? If so, then why the above diagram shows multiple `WebApplicationContext`s of middle tier components and single `WebApplicationContext` of web tier component?

Comment: 1) Both `WebApplicationContext` and `ApplicationContext` are *interfaces*, so when documentation says "creates `ApplicationContext` instance" it means that it creates an object instance of a class that implements `ApplicationContext`. Whether that class *also* implements `WebApplicationContext` is besides the point. It may. It may not. Doesn't invalidate the statement that it "creates `ApplicationContext` instance".

Comment: ohh thats bummer...How did I not notice that. When we create normal Spring MVC app with web.xml, it creates [`XmlWebApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/XmlWebApplicationContext.html)? Also can you answer the other two questions...or they are senseless?

Answer (score 1):

1. Both `WebApplicationContext` and `ApplicationContext` are *interfaces*, so when documentation says "creates `ApplicationContext` instance" it means that it creates an object instance of a class that implements `ApplicationContext`. Whether that class *also* implements `WebApplicationContext` is besides the point. It may. It may not. Doesn't invalidate the statement that it "creates `ApplicationContext` instance".
2. > *what usually online articles refer to as "root"*

   No, it's what the javadoc of [`ContextLoaderListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html) *itself* refers to a root:

   > Performs the actual initialization work for the **root** application context.
3. > *why the above diagram shows multiple `WebApplicationContexts` of middle tier components and single `WebApplicationContext` of web tier component?*

   It only shows a single `WebApplicationContext` of web tier component because the diagram is for a single `DispatcherServlet`.

   Just because `ContextLoaderListener` only creates a single root context, doesn't mean that multiple contexts couldn't be created by other means. The diagram accurately shows what is possible.

Comment: Thanks, that clears considerable amount of confusion in my mind. But a new little confusion created by "Just because ContextLoaderListener only creates a single root context, doesn't mean that multiple contexts couldn't be created by other means." Can you elaborate / give small example which "other means"?

Comment: @anir E.g. write your own listener and create however many contexts you want, split however you want.